# How to connect a database to a backend in minicube?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I want to start a minikube cluster with a data base and a java backend.

I have a persistent volume and the service for the mariadb database with the following persistent, claim and delpoyment

- [MariaDBpasteBin](https://ptpb.pw/9iY3)

and the java backend with the deployment and service

- [javaPastebin](https://ptpb.pw/3TxD)

in addition my java backend uses dropwizard and I specify the database address and all the credentials in a `config.yml`

```
logging:
  level: INFO
  loggers:
    DropwizardBackend.org: DEBUG
dataBase:
  driverClass: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
  user: <userName>
  password: <password>
  url: jdbc:mariadb://<database address>:<port>/<database Name>
```

Since my java backend needs to connect to the database to run at the moment I get a error message since the specified data base can not be found. I was wondering what the address of the database is? Do I have to specify it like the external IP of the java-deployment? How ever I prefer if only the backend is able to access the database.

Comment: You need the DNS name of the Service that points at the database.  The Kubernetes documentation has [a complete example of a MySQL+Wordpress deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/) that has a lot of example YAML you can borrow from.

Comment: If I understand correctly the kubernetes wordpress deployment uses environment variables to connect to the database 
    `name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST \n  value: wordpress-mysql` 
how would I point to the DNS of my database

Comment: `wordpress-mysql` there is a DNS name (the FQDN would be `wordpress-mysql.default.svc.cluster.local`) and it matches the name of the Service in the first part of that tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your yaml it seems you have named the mariaDB service "maria" so the dns name for it should be just `maria` (if you are in the same namespace) or `maria.<namespace>` (from all other namespaces) or `maria.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local` as a FQDN.

Comment: Is that this simple to just write `maria` into dropwizard `config.yml` as database address? I am very new to this container orchestration so I can not believe it is that simple.

Comment: Yes, it should be that simple. It will resolve the dns name "maria" into the virtual ip the service holds. You can try it if you `exec` into the java container and run `dig maria`

Comment: Dear Andreas, You are great! thanks for taking the time and going over my `.yml` files